# Why Facebook Graph Request to read Timeline posts return error message with null content?

Tags: android, rest, facebook-graph-api, httprequest, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am creating an Android App that fetches Facebook timeline posts of the logged in user. I using Facebook SDK for Android 4.27.0

**My Problem**
 Now the problem is , after the graph request executed , the graph request return error messages with null content . (But Graph Request to retrive profile info is success).

So tried two types of methods that initiates Graph Request

> - GraphRequest.newMeRequest ()
> - new GraphRequest(.....)

Both are returning error messages .

> - Tried accessing non-existing field (Message) on node type (user)
> - {data:[]}

**My Code ::**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String email="===",name="====";

    TextView txtstatus,txt3;
    LoginButton login_button;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        intializeControls();
        LoginWithFB();

    }

    private void intializeControls()
    {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        login_button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends","user_posts", "user_status")); // Setting permissions
    }

    void LoginWithFB ()
    {
        login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

                final Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                txtstatus.setText("Login Success" );

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(   //To read profile Info
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {
                                    TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                                    TextView nametext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
                                    txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


                                    // Application code
                                    name = object.getString("name");
                                    email = object.getString("email");

                                    nametext.setText(name);
                                    txt2.setText(email);


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

                //Now graph Query to read timeline posts
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("fields", "message,created_time,id,full_picture,status_type,source,comments.summary(true),likes.summary(true)");
                params.putString("limit", "10");

    /* make the API call */
                //Method - 1
                GraphRequest requestPost = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(   //To read profile Info
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {
                                    txt3.setText(response.toString());


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                requestPost.setParameters(params);
                requestPost.executeAsync();

                //Method - 2
                new GraphRequest( loginResult.getAccessToken(), "/me/posts", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            /* handle the result */
                                TextView postsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postText);
                                postsText.setText(response.toString());

                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                txtstatus.setText("Login canceled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                txtstatus.setText("Login failed"+error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
  }
```

**The Output::**

---

[image: This the error I am getting]

=This the error I got

---

**My steps to resolve :** 
I used the Method 2 first , but it returned data::null , so I tried the Method-1 , it also returned error message only.

But both error messages are different . Since I am new to Facebook SDK , I can't resolve on my own.

Please guide me to resolve this error.

Comment: try this:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/feed

Comment: @nomag , yes , I am already included it in my code   new GraphRequest( loginResult.getAccessToken(), "/me/posts", ...... I tried all endpoints /posts , /feed etc .. no solution

Comment: do you have access to permission "user_posts" ?

Comment: @nomag   yes. I added that using the code :: = login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends","user_posts", "user_status"));

Comment: @RageshDAntony: By just adding does not mean that you got the required permission. You need to submit apk to facebook with valid reasons to get it approved. Does this permission shows up during login screen ? No ..right? You may debug and check which are permissions are granted and which are denied using GraphResponse

Comment: Does this permission shows up during login screen ? No ...    After username & password screen , it asks "Continue as <username>" , after clicks continue , it enter into the activity shown in the above image

Comment: You need to submit apk to facebook with valid reasons to get it approved.////////    Then how can I use facebook graph API for learning purposes .. @nomag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156263/discussion-between-nomag-and-ragesh-d-antony).

Comment: @nomag .. The problem resolved .. it succesfully fetched posts from FB account after I Logged in with my FB account with  developer account and that developer FB account  associated with this app. That is  it is fetching only my developer FB account.

Comment: And When I logged in , the permission page show a warning that "The app needed to be submited for review "

Comment: Before this I used my personal ID (with developer privileges) because It had lot of posts ...But after using my dev FB id , fetching success

Comment: @nomag  . THANK YOU very much for clearing my problem .. Bye